# How to get list of pods which are "ready"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am using kubectl in order to retrieve a list of pods:

```
 kubectl get pods --selector=artifact=boot-example -n my-sandbox
```

The results which I am getting are:

```
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
boot-example-757c4c6d9c-kk7mg   0/1     Running   0          77m
boot-example-7dd6cd8d49-d46xs   1/1     Running   0          84m
boot-example-7dd6cd8d49-sktf8   1/1     Running   0          88m
```

I would like to get only those pods which are "**ready**" (passed readinessProbe). Is there any kubectl command which returns only "**ready**" pods? If not kubectl command, then maybe some other way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
kubectl -n your-namespace get pods -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,POD:metadata.name,PodIP:status.podIP,READY-true:status.containerStatuses[*].ready | grep true
```

This will return you the pods with containers that are "**ready**".

To do this without grep, you can use the following commands:

```
kubectl -n your-namespace get pods -o go-template='{{range $index, $element := .items}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{if .ready}}{{$element.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'

kubectl -n your-namespace get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.status.containerStatuses[*].ready.true}{.metadata.name}{ "\n"}{end}'
```

This will return you the pod names that are "**ready**".

Comment: This is a solution without any external tools besides kubectl to return you the "Ready" field with other data of the pod.
You can use grep to filter only the pods with "Ready" as "true"

Comment: This works for me. Anyhow I still will wait for an answer which uses pure kubectl  (without grep)

Comment: I have edited the answer to provide a solution without using grep as well.
The new command will return you the pod names that are "ready".

Comment: later versions of kubectl can now just do this - kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running

Comment: @nrjohnstone, status.phase=Running doesn't mean pod ready.

Comment: the `jsonpath` output generator does not appear to work [anymore?]. The `go-template` generator outputs duplicate entries [now?] :(

Answer (score 9):

Generic answer for all resource type which prints READY state when queried using `kubectl get <resource-name>` command.

```
kubectl get pod |grep -P '\s+([1-9]+[\d]*)\/\1\s+'
```

Example:

```
kubectl get pod
NAME   READY  STATUS     RESTARTS  AGE
app_1   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_2   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_3   0/1    Completed  0         77m
app_4   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_5   8/8    Running    0         77m
app_6   4/4    Running    1         77m
app_7   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_8   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_9   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_10  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_11  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_12  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_13  1/1    Running    0         75m
app_14  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_15  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_16  2/2    Running    0         76m
app_17  4/8    Running    0         77m
app_18  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_19  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_20  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_21  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_22  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_23  3/3    Running    0         77m
app_24  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_25  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_26  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_27  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_28  2/2    Running    0         77m
```

Sample output:

```
kubectl get pod| grep -P '\s+([1-9]+)\/\1\s+'
app_1   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_2   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_4   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_5   8/8    Running    0         77m
app_6   4/4    Running    1         77m
app_7   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_8   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_9   1/1    Running    0         77m
app_10  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_11  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_12  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_13  1/1    Running    0         75m
app_14  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_15  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_16  2/2    Running    0         76m
app_18  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_19  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_20  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_21  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_22  2/2    Running    0         77m
app_23  3/3    Running    0         77m
app_24  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_25  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_26  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_27  1/1    Running    0         77m
app_28  2/2    Running    0         77m
```

To print resources not in ready state:

```
kubectl get pod |grep -Pv '\s+([1-9]+[\d]*)\/\1\s+'
NAME   READY  STATUS     RESTARTS  AGE
app_3   0/1    Completed  0         77m
app_17  4/8    Running    0         77m
```

Those interested in the `grep` command, recommending to read the concept of "capture groups" and "back referencing" in regular expressions. However, a brief description is added here.

`\s+([1-9]+)\/\1\s+`

Explanation:

`\s` matches any whitespace character
`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible

`1st` Capturing Group `([1-9]+)`

Match a single character present in the list below `[1-9]`
`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
`1-9` matches a single character in the range between `1`  and `9`
`\/` matches the character / literally
`\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group, which in this case is `[1-9]+`

`\s` matches any whitespace character
`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimit

Comment: Can you explain your grep voodoo?

Comment: @Slashterix added few notes, however recommending to read the concept of "capture groups" and "back referencing" in regular expressions.

Comment: in many instance grep -P perl match will not work, so gets difficult to depend on -P option of grep

Comment: @P.... What is the difference between
\s+([1-9]+[\d]*)\/\1\s+ and 
\s+([1-9]+)\/\1\s+

To be specific, ([1-9]+[\d]*) and ([1-9]+). Why do you need [\d]* when all the digits are already searched with [1-9]+ itself?

Answer (score 6):

You can try this command which uses jq to transform kubectl json output as you require.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json  | jq -r '.items[] | select(.status.phase = "Ready" or ([ .status.conditions[] | select(.type == "Ready") ] | length ) == 1 ) | .metadata.namespace + "/" + .metadata.name'
```

Comment: Unfornatunaly I do not have "jq" command. I got error message: "bash: jq: command not found"

Comment: reverted back, i did a mistake, 2nd command really shows not ready pods.. Install and use jq:) Its amazingly useful :)

Comment: the solution should be not only for me but for my colleagues too.The less steps they need to do the better.

Comment: @vit, can you help me adapt it to get Running and conditions ready status = False? kubectl get pods -n qa2 -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.status.phase = "Running" and ([ .status.conditions[] | select(.type == "Ready" and .status == "False") ] | length ) == 1 ) | .metadata.name

Answer (score 1):

After reading answers posted here & using some of them as reference (so my solution is sort of derived from others answers), here is what I am using to figure out fully ready pods (i.e running (`status.phase=Running`) pods having all of its containers in ready state , (i.e `containerStatuses[*].ready=true`))

```
kubectl get pods -l app="myservice-service" --field-selector status.phase=Running -o 'custom-columns="NAME":.metadata.name,"READY":.status.containerStatuses[*].ready,"STATUS":.status.phase' | awk '$2 !~ /.*false.*/'
NAME                                   READY       STATUS
myservice-service-74dc69d4-7t662   true,true   Running
myservice-service-74dc69d4-d4mtz   true,true   Running
```

- `awk` to remove pods having one or more nonready (i.e `ready=false`) containers
- `--field-selector` for getting only `Running` pods
- `custom-columns` for printing custom columns , important one is `ready` column

Comment: Ya this also nice, without depending on grep.

Comment: Simplified your awk expression `kubectl get pods -o 'custom-columns="NAME":.metadata.name,"READY":.status.containerStatuses[*].ready,"STATUS":.status.phase' | awk '$2~/true/'`

Comment: `awk '$2~/true/'` will also return pods having only single container in ready state. Because of this I had to exclusively use `awk '$2 !~ /.*false.*/'`

Comment: Oh.. got it.. 

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for i in $(k get po -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}')
    do
        if [[ $(kubectl  get po $i -o jsonpath='{.status.containerStatuses[*].ready}') == 'true'  ]]
            then 
                echo $i
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `field-selector` option from the native `kubectl` CLI to filter out non-running pods:

`kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running`

By using the native CLI you can use the custom column filter as part of the same single command for additional output customization:

`kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name`

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. status.phase=Running returns terminating pods as well.

Comment: apart from running, you also need to check if ready field also shows all containers ready.. ex: 1/1 or 2/2 or 4/4 both should be same number.. else it will be meaning some containers are not yet ready..

Answer (score 0):

This simple approach worked good for me.
This will list only completely Ready pods.

```
kubectl get pods <options> | grep -P "(\d+)\/\1\s+Running"
```

This will check both the conditions.

1. STATUS = Running
2. All containers in Pod also ready

Explanation of reg-ex:
`(\d+)` number one or more occurrence and parenthesis indicates 1st set
`\/` followed by a slash character
`\1` match again with the same value of first set
`\s+` one or more spaces
`Running` the literal word "Running".

This will ensure that READY column have, both sides same number like 1/1 or 2/2 etc
and next status column should be equal to Running

Comment: This is helpful . It lists only those pods of which all containers are in Ready state . The only addition I would prefer on top of this is to add some validation of image tag . Let's say we are creating a shell script which runs after deployment verifying that pods are running with expected image tag . How can we do this with above command ?

Comment: @sjethvani for that you can apply awk on `kubectl get deployments -o wide`, you need to verify on 7th column which shows image name with tag, and also in same you can also check ready state with same above logic.

Comment: Sorry , it seems above basic `awk '$2~/([1-9]+)\/{1}/` itself is not working . It prints pods (even though its containers are not ready)


```sam.jeth@sam-jeth-C0123dsdGHASSA ~ % kubectl get pods -l app="myservice-service" --field-selector status.phase=Running --no-headers | awk '$2~/([1-9]+)\/{1}/ && $3~/Running/'```

Output
```myservice-service-74dc69d4-2jb9z   1/2   Running   0     47s
myservice-service-74dc69d4-97gmr   1/2   Running   0     47s
myservice-service-74dc69d4-wnkhb   2/2   Running   0     62s```

Comment: @sjethvani, yes you are right, awk follows simple POSIX reg-ex, for this we need some thing called back reference .. I have corrected by replacing awk to grep..

Comment: For grep , I am getting `grep: invalid option -- P` . Let me explore further. Will update here once I get some answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems this one is working , returning only pods (in Running phase) as well as having all containers in ready state 

```kubectl get pods -l app="myservice-service" --field-selector status.phase=Running -o 'custom-columns="NAME":.metadata.name,"READY":.status.containerStatuses[*].ready,"STATUS":.status.phase' | awk '$2 !~ /.*false.*/'```

Comment: Added above solution as an answer. Thanks Karthik for your answer as a reference. Please review mine & do comment if you find any issue in it .

Comment: `-P` of grep is Perl kind of reg-ex, and on some machines this can be missing.. so it is showing `grep: invalid option -- P`

Answer (score 0):

@sjethvani

If you're willing to use jq... you can do FAR more interesting things with much better cross-platform support for the command. Something like this is much less limited than something like jsonpath

```
kubectl get pods -n online-boutique --field-selector=status.phase==Running -o=json | jq -r '.items[] | "---", "pod_name: " + .metadata.name, "containers:", (.spec.containers[] | "- container_name: " + .name, "  image_path: " + (.image | split(":")[0]), "  image_tag: " + (.image | split(":")[1])), "---"'
```

sample

```
---
pod_name: adservice-795589cf6f-b48ln
containers:
- container_name: server
  image_path: gcr.io/google-samples/microservices-demo/adservice
  image_tag: v0.5.1
---
```

Comment: Yup have been using `jq` a lot , infact I have silo commands using jq for diff asks like (count of pods deployed with expected image version is matching with total no of pods in service namespace to consider deployment successful etc). 
For this case(where I need to list out only pods having all containers in ready state) , using `awk` seems more elegant & hence am using it for my usecase

Comment: I totally agree that awk can look better at times; it's just less flexible when trying to do things like image validation and whatnot; but I'm glad you've got something that works for you.

If you're every wanting to share some of those siloed commands that you're proud of, we're starting a community around it - you can use this github issue to share any command you think could show up in a community cheat sheet: https://github.com/runwhen-contrib/runwhen-local/issues/new/choose