# kubectl get pods: Field Selectors

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm running this command:

```
# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=metadata.namespace!=kube-system,metadata.namespace!=monitoring,metadata.namespace!=rtf
```

Which gives me output like this:

```
NAMESPACE                        NAME              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
123456-1234-1234-1234-123456789  some-app-123456   2/2     Running   0          10m
123456-1234-1234-1234-123456789  some-app-789112   1/2     Running   0          10m
```

I would like to be able to filter on the READY column, but I can't seem to find the right field-selector value.

Is this possible?

I've tried searching around for a list of available field-selectors, and haven't had any luck. It's possible that one doesn't exist.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992774/how-to-get-list-of-pods-which-are-ready

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Thanks for the link! I tried to modify the answer in the link for ready.true to be ready.false, and it gives me the same information however. I'm not sure I'm using it correctly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `kubectl get pods` supports `field selectors` based on the `READY` column directly.

But `kubectl` provides a method exporting the resource configuration (YAML) directly into `JSON, -o json`. Then, we can use `jq` to read, parse, and mutate K8s object results from `kubectl`.

In your case, you could use a command like this to filter all pods (excluding the `pods` from namespaces `kube-system`, `monitoring` & `rtf`) not in `ready` state:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=metadata.namespace!=kube-system,metadata.namespace!=monitoring,metadata.namespace!=rtf -ojson | jq '.items[] | select(.status.containerStatuses[].ready==false) | .metadata.namespace + "/" + .metadata.name'
```

and/or change `ready=true` to get the pods in `ready` state.

Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/geekculture/my-jq-cheatsheet-34054df5b650) article for many more such uses of `jq` with `kubectl`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could be improved by displaying `namespace/name ` instead of only the name.

Comment: Yeah, good for readability. Updated the answer.